# MacOS Desktops for Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments

Anyone who knows of MacOS-like desktop window manager that runs on Ubuntu?

Having left Win2k around 2000 for SuSE, dropping SUSE for OSX in 2010, and now dropping MacOS (Software and Desktop) for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, I've come to like the minimalism of the MacOS-Desktop, but hating its HPFS/APFS Filesystem and BSD environment. I work a lot with CentOS Servers, but would switch all Office Workstations to a future oriented OS like Ubuntu LTS. The Unity Desktop was quite OK for me, but would like to have a MacOS-Like Work environment. I looked at ZorinOS, but it does not support any MacBookPro's atm. QUBES just reboots during the installation and re-installs.

The aim is an Ubuntu Host with a MacOS-Like Desktop equvalent to ZorinOS's strategy (but stable and running on MacBookPro's) and running Whonix WS & GW on some, and a plain Office WS on others.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a similar appearance, however as far as running Mac programs I don't think there is such an animal.

https://www.noobslab.com/2018/08/macbuntu-1804-transformation-pack-ready.html